# Prosciutto and Cantaloupe

Tags: fruit

Here's a pic of an appetizer I'd like to replicate. Can you tell me how to slice the prosciutto and cantaloupe and plate it? Thanks[image]

Comment: @SteveChambers when you are replying to the question posted, please do it in an answer. Comments are for requesting clarification.

Comment: Personal advice beside aesthetic consideration. Sliced melon tend to be less "pulpy" and more rigid in mouth.  Overall it seems to taste less as compared to tick wedges. I did indulge on plating of that sort but stopped because it is not worth of.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, your deli/charcuterie store will slice the prosciutto for you, either manually or with a meat slicer (more often).

The melon, is thinly sliced manually, just pick a ripe melon, halve it and slice it up and remove the rind.

Depending on the thickness of the slices, you will be able to make fancy folds like in the picture, or maybe not, then you will just have nice slices.

Melon and Prosciutto is a simple dish where ingredients is more important than presentation.

i personally, just slice the melon in wedges and drape the ham over it, or roll the ham around pieces of melon.

Comment: I agree, but that plate is very pretty